# Javascript creating object properties using existing object property

Tags: javascript

This is what I would like to do

```
var myObject = {
  prop: "872349827194721934798",
  calcProp: (this.prop.length % 3),
  method1: function () { return this.calcProp; },
  method2: function () { return this.calcProp - 1; }
}
```

However it returns an error **"this.prop is undefined"**.

Below works:

```
var myObject = {
  prop: "872349827194721934798",
  calcProp: function () {this.prop.length % 3;},
  method1: function () { return this.calcProp(); },
  method2: function () ( return this.calcProp() - 1;}
}
```

Now the usage of calcProp is `myObject.calcProp()' and I want the usage to be`myObject.calcProp`.  I know this will work.

```
var myObject = {
  init: function () { this.calcProp = this.prop.length % 3; },
  prop: "872349827194721934798",
  calcProp: null,
  method1: function () { 
    this.init();
    return this.calcProp; 
  },
  method2: function () { 
    this.init();
    return this.calcProp - 1;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to implement `calcProp` where the usage is `Object.calcprop`. Without calling an `init()`.

**EDITED - Additional Requirement**

---

**Note:** Should have added to my requirements that I would like to try to stay away from modifying the properties outside of the initial definition. I do not want to do the following;

```
var myObject = {
  prop: "872349827194721934798",
  method1: function () { return this.calcProp; },
  method2: function () { return this.calcProp - 1; }
};
myObject.calcProp = (myObject.prop.length % 3);
```

I would like to keep it all in the initial definition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Comment: @FelixKling  No this is not a duplicate because I do not want to create an init function.  I like the solution that Daniel Earwicker provided.

Comment: @JohnHartsock: your `I would like to try to stay away from modifying the properties outside the initial definition` is not possible.  JS is a scripting language and cannot self reference as it is being defined.   You can sort of do this after, but you don't seem to  want that.

Comment: Actually I lied --- you can use `get`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853523/javascript-creating-object-properties-using-existing-object-property/7854198#7854198) below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myObject = {
  prop     : "872349827194721934798",
  get calcProp(){ return this.prop.length % 3; },
  method1  : function () { return this.calcProp; },
  method2  : function () { return this.calcProp - 1; }
};
```

---

***Example use:*** `console.log(myObject.calcProp);`

***Note:*** `get` was introduced in ECMAScript5/Harmony, so if the JS engines weren't updated on older browsers, it may not work in those cases.  Refer to [Daniel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853523/javascript-creating-object-properties-using-existing-object-property/7853566#7853566) for something a little more support in older browsers.

Comment: NB this behaves very differently. If `prop` is modified, a plain `calcProp` value will not change. But if `calcProp` is a dynamic property defined by a getter, it will change when `prop` changes as it is recalculated on every access.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: I think he wanted calcProp to be the result of a function, without using the parenthetical syntax.  The above does as you described: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/M6d2X/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var myObject = {
  prop: "872349827194721934798",
  method1: function () { return this.calcProp; },
  method2: function () { return this.calcProp - 1; };
};
myObject.calcProp = (myObject.prop.length % 3);
```

Or to allow this to be done inline, write a helper:

```
function alloc(init) {
    var o = {};
    init.call(o);
    return o;
}
```

You can now say:

```
var myObject = alloc(function() {
   this.prop = "872349827194721934798";
   this.calcProp = (this.prop.length % 3);
   this.method1 = function () { return this.calcProp; };
   this.method2 = function () { return this.calcProp - 1; };
});
```

Comment: Should have added to my requirements that I would like to try to stay away from modifying the properties outside of the initial definition.

Comment: See update: there is no way to use object initialisation syntax in the way you want to because it doesn't expose a name for the semi-constructed object. The `alloc` function I've added does the minimum to expose a name for a blank object and then call a function to set it up.

Comment: You can accomplish this without the `alloc` function by treating the anonymous function as a constructor: `var myObject = new function() { /* all the same */ };` [jsFiddle Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/yTLKH/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the object before you can access its members.

```
var myObject = { 
  prop: "872349827194721934798", 
  method1: function () { return this.calcProp; }, 
  method2: function () { return this.calcProp - 1; } 
};
myObject.calcProp = myObject.prop.length % 3;
```

In the context of your object literal expression, `this` refers to the expression's context - likely the `window`.  You get an undefined error, because your current context contains no `prop` property.  If the context had a member named `prop`, that value would be used:

```
var prop = [];
var myObject = {
  prop: "872349827194721934798",    
  calcProp: (this.prop.length % 3),    
  method1: function () { return this.calcProp; },    
  method2: function () { return this.calcProp - 1; }    
};
myObject.calcProp; // 0 (ie, [].length % 3)
```

**Edit:** You shouldn't need to access the property, just use the same value.  Eg:

```
var myObject = {
  prop: "some literal string",
  calcProp: "some literal string".length % 3
};
```

or

```
var myObject = {
  prop: someVariable,
  calcProp: someVariable.length % 3
};
```

Or, here's another approach:

```
function SomeObj(prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
    this.calcProp = this.prop.length % 3;
}
SomeObj.prototype.method1 = function () { return this.calcProp; };
SomeObj.prototype.method2 = function () { return this.calcProp - 1; };

var myObject = new SomeObj("872349827194721934798");
```

Comment: Should have added to my requirements that I would like to try to stay away from modifying the properties outside of the initial definition.

Comment: @JohnHartsock - The property of the object does not exist until the object has been created.  You can't access a property of an object that doesn't exist.  See my edit for another approach that may get you closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: Daniel Earwicker has a very clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice but to do initialization by parts

```
var obj = { prop: ... };
obj.calcProp = ...
```

You can use some tricks to still be able to write this inline though:

```
//the module pattern allows for inline statements
var fullObj =(function(){
    var obj = { prop: ... };
    obj.calcProp = ...
    return obj;
}());

//a constructor function gives you unlimited power:
function init(obj){
    obj.calcProp = ...
    return obj;
}
var something = init({
    prop: "123"
    ...
});
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your second scenario...Why did you wrap the obj in stuff?

Comment: It was just an example of a case where you need to put things inline in an expression instead of spread over multiple statements. (Removed it anyway)

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: The thing is *you can't get what you are hoping for*. The literal syntax doen't handle circular references so the best you can do is try to make the process of splitting things into multiple statements more pleasant (for example, the module pattern avoids creating any variables that will polute the outlying scope)

Comment: Daniel Earwicker provided a very clever solution to keep my code together as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the same as the other answers:

```
 var propVal = "872349827194721934798";
    var myObject = {
      prop: propVal ,
      calcProp: (propVal.length % 3),
      method1: function () { return this.calcProp; },
      method2: function () { return this.calcProp - 1; }
    }
```

Comment: Should have added to my requirements that I would like to try to stay away from modifying the properties outside of the initial definition.